# Simple celsius to fahrenheit program on python not working because of wrong coding. The program should run via loop

Tags: python

```
a=int(input("Enter any number: "))
b=float(a*9//5)+32
print(b)
for x in range(5,50,b):
    print (x)
```

I am getting this error:

```
Enter any number: 43                                                                                                                                                               
109.0                                                                                                                                                                              
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                 
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>                                                                                                                                              
    for x in range(5,50,b):                                                                                                                                                        
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: `for x in range(5,50,int(b)):`

Comment: The interval parameter in python range cannot be a float. You would need either numpy or a different loop to do that. `x = 5; while x < 50: print(x); x += b`

Answer (score 0):

The `step` argument to `range` should be an integer ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range)).

Since you're doing floor division (`9//5`) you're guaranteed `b` will be a whole number, so you might consider rewriting the line that defines `b`:

```
>>> a = 2
>>> b = (a * 9 // 5) + 32
>>> b
35
```

Then the rest of your code will work as-is.

Sample output:

```
Enter any number: 4
39
5
44
```

I'm guessing you intend to multiply by 1.8 though, so you will need to keep `b` as a float and do normal division. In that case, you might try a `while` loop instead:

```
a = int(input("Enter any number: "))
b = a * 9 / 5 + 32  # one slash instead of two
print(b)

x = 5
while x < 50:
    print(x)
    x += b
```

Sample output:

```
Enter any number: 1
33.8
5
38.8
```

Note this code works for Python 3, where `9/5 = 1.8`. For Python 2, integer division defaults to floor division - `9/5 = 1` - so you'd need to write:

```
b = a * (9.0 / 5) + 32
```

instead.